# IE is telling me I have mixed SSL content when I don't

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl

In IE it is giving me the "some items on the page are not secure" message. I have tracked it down to this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/prototype.js"></script>
```

which is a lightbox script I downloaded. I tried making the src relative or absolute with https it happens either way. And only in IE.

Heres the page if you need to see it: [Clicky](https://www.kranichs.com/cart.php)

Thanks!

Comment: I get no errors at the moment in IE8, but your page is bombing with script and php errors so those probably need fixed first...

Comment: both ie6 and 7, the errors stop if I remove the line above. I have removed it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your page in Fiddler, I see a request to https://www.kranichs.com/images/bottombax_02.jpg, which is a 404.

IE considers the 404 error message as unsafe content, so if you are including that (in an IFRAME or something) then you will see the mixed content error.  Fix that and see what happens.

If nothing changes when that file exists, and you don't see any HTTP requests in Fiddler, it's possibly the [removeChild](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925014) problem - if you remove a DIV with a background image (as a lightbox might) then you will see the mixed content error.

Comment: FWIW: A securely-returned 404 will not cause this problem.  A redirect from a secure page to an insecure page, OTOH, will.

Comment: I was referring to the page that it displays if you don't provide a specific 404 page yourself, but I trust that you'll know better than I here.  Thanks for Fiddler, Eric; I'd be lost without it!